# YAML file syntax

Tags: syntax, yaml

I'm working with a yaml file that I'm not supposed to break it. The problem is I'm not familiar with it, so is not sure if I can change some of its format...

The source file we received looks like this:
    `- items:
    - heading: Maps
      description: >
        Integrate 3D buildings and tacos.
      image_path: /music/images/v2/web_api-music.png`

After processing the files, it looks like this:
    `- items:
    - heading: Maps
      description: > Integrate 3D buildings and tacos.
      image_path: /music/images/v2/web_api-music.png`

Does it break the code if the line break is missing between the greater than sign and the string? Would it have any potential impact on the UI format?

Also does it matter if there's extra spaces before "Integrate 3D buildings and tacos"? like below 
`- items:
    - heading: Maps
      description: >
          Integrate 3D buildings and tacos.
      image_path: /music/images/v2/web_api-music.png`

Thank you and happy Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 1):

See the [spec for the version of yaml you are interested in](http://www.yaml.org/)

Generally speaking, the `>` is only significant at the end of the line, and means that the subsequent indented block should be folded on to this line with all newlines and leading/trailing space removed (replaced by sinlge spaces.)  So

```
- heading: Maps
  description: >
    Integrate 3D buildings and tacos.
  image_path: /music/images/v2/web_api-music.png
```

would be equivalent to

```
- heading: Maps
  description: Integrate 3D buildings and tacos.
```

and leaving the `>` in when you remove the newline essentially adds it to the string value.

Changing the amount of indentation of any given block is generally irrelevant, as long as the lines of a block are consistently indented

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried to validate the processed file one: description: > Integrate 3D buildings and tacos(without line break). The online validator said it is valid...but based on your guys description, it is not valid...I'm a bit confused. Do you know why?

Comment: Its valid -- it just has an extra '>' in the value for the description that was not there before.  So by doing this, you've changed the meaning of the file, giving you different (but still valid yaml) contents.

Comment: Thank you Chris! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to check your files using some online YAML validator. For example: [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/). Also, there are libraries for many languages, so if possible I recommend you use one of these to process your yaml files.

Your first processes file is not valid. There should be a newline after the `>`, or you can leave out the `>`.

Your last example is valid. The amount of indentation doesn't matter. From [the spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534):

> The amount of indentation is a presentation detail and must not be used to convey content information.
>
> [...]
>
> Each node must be indented further than its parent node. All sibling nodes must use the exact same indentation level. However the content of each sibling node may be further indented independently.